# `pushd` command for shell buffer

Tags: shell, directory

In an interactive shell, I have a script I run that changes my directory (via `pushd`) and then launches an interactive program.  At this point I issue `M-x cd` and provide Emacs with the new directory that the script placed me in.  What I'd like to do is `M-x pushd` (or equivalent) so that when I exit the program, my subsequent command-line `popd` will be recognized by Emacs to adjust my directory accordingly.

Comment: Where are you when you enter M-x cd - in the shell buffer?

Comment: Yes, in the shell buffer, in order to tell it what the new directory is.

Comment: You can use the command `shell-resync-dirs`, bound to `M-return` by default, in place of `M-x cd`. This tells Emacs to sort out the current directory for your shell buffer. After that, issuing `cd -` at the command line will take you back to the previous directory. In your case, entering `cd -` may be all that you need to return to the previous directory after your program?

Comment: Thanks -- I have 'C-c d' mapped to `dirs` (an alias for `shell-resync-dirs`); I'll try to start using M-RET instead.  I run `dirs` after I exit the script and issue `popd` (because `dirs` fails without a shell).  What I'd like is for the buffer's associated directory to change when I launch the script so that file completion works while the script is running.